# Printing a PDF with overlaid text fields

Tags: java, pdf

I'm using Java.

I don't think I need to "fill" a PDF, as I think this is more complicated. What I have is a 2-page pdf called EmploymentApplication.pdf. It has empty spaces for Last Name, First Name, SSN, etc.

I just want to print the existing pdf with some overlaid text fields (which I populate programmatically) in the appropriate position. I can do this on an image - I believe it's called "watermarking" - and convert to PDF but I wanted to save a step.

Comment: If all you need is to print the form with the overlay combined, you can simply print the resulting image directly. For example, using something like the [LEADTOOLS SDK](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/image-processing) you can simply call [RasterCodecs.Load](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/dh/co/rastercodecs-load.html) for each image, combine them using the [CombineCommand](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/dh/pe/combinecommand.html) class, before putting the output in a print job and send it to the printer. (Disclaimer: I work for the vendor of the toolkit)